# for loop in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random variable not changing in “for” loop in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500217/random-variable-not-changing-in-for-loop-in-windows-batch-file)

I have text file with list of files I want to rename. This is my code:

```
for /f %%i in (tmp.txt) do set script_name=%%i & ren %script_name% %script_name:~0,9%%num%%script_name:~15,9%.sql
```

But in second part it takes `%script_name%` only in the first iteration of the loop. So

```
ren %script_name% %script_name:~0,9%%num%%script_name:~15,9%.sql
```

always do the same.

Please help to fix that.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500217/random-variable-not-changing-in-for-loop-in-windows-batch-file) is basically about the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `set /?` and then explore delayed environment expansion. You would first

`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`
 (look at `setlocal /?` as well) and then wrap variables in `ren` with !'s rather than %'s. I would also use && concatenating the commands, so the first one completes before the second one starts.

Comment: `&&` implies checking the result of executing the previous command, `&` doesn't. Also it's `EnableDelayedExpansion` (`EnableExtensions` is about something different).