# Batch - break a string by a delimiting character and set the value to variable and echo variable in a file

Tags: batch-file

I need to brake a variable into two base on slash `\` delimiter and then set the second value to a variable and print it in a file. Here is my code

```
set string=somestuff\needthis\ok

If NOT "%string%"=="%string:somestuff=%" (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%a in ("%string%") do (set "mystuff=%%b"
    echo %mystuff% >> myfile.txt
    )
) else (
    echo No >> myfile.txt
)
```

Problem Point : if I directly echo `%%b` then that will be printed in `myfile.text` but if I assign it to variable and then try to echo the variable value it don't print anything.

Comment: You need to `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and then `ECHO !mystuff!` instead

Comment: @Compo you're 21 seconds faster then me.....

Comment: duplicate: [for loop in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6680409/995714), [windows batch files: setting variable in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5615206/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [for loop in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680409/for-loop-in-batch-file)