# Batch- generating a random number of random numbers

Tags: batch-file, random

As part of a program I'm making, I want to be able to 'plot' or 'mark' random points on a grid. In doing so I need to generate a random number(x) to determine the number of plots- and then x amount of different random numbers representing coordinates. At the moment I have the following code:

```
@echo off
:obno
set /a r1=%random%
if %r1% gtr 10 goto obno else (
goto ob
)

:ob
for /L %%R in (1,1,%r1%) do set /a n%%R=%random%*240/32678+1
echo %r1%
echo %n1% %n2% %n3% %n4% %n5% %n6% %n7% %n8% %n9% %n10%
pause
```

What happens here is I end up with x amount of the same random number instead of different ones

i.e. ouput:

```
5
108 108 108 108 108
```

so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you think is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In a loop you should be using delayed expansion e.g.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and using !RANDOM! instead of %RANDOM%
```

And...

```
%RANDOM% gives you a random number between 0 and 32767.
```

Using an expression like below you can change the range to anything you like (here the range is [1…100] instead of [0…32767]).

```
SET /A test=%RANDOM% * 100 / 32768 + 1
```

And below will produce number between 1~100

```
set /a num=%random% %%100 +1
```

To get a random number between 0 and 9 on the command line, use

```
set /a "rand=%random% % 10"
```

If used in a batch file then double the modulo operator

```
set /a "rand=%random% %% 10"
```

Comment: ah I tried using setlocal 
    'enabledelayedexpansion'
without using the !

Comment: If your issue got resolved...you can select this as a right answer !

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, you can use a `call` and double the `%` to make `%%random%%`

```
@echo off
:obno
set /a r1=%random%
if %r1% gtr 10 goto obno else (
goto ob
)

:ob
for /L %%R in (1,1,%r1%) do call set /a n%%R=%%random%%*240/32678+1
echo %r1%
echo %n1% %n2% %n3% %n4% %n5% %n6% %n7% %n8% %n9% %n10%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simliar post to generate random numbers in a batch file

You need to include the following at the start of your batch file

```
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

[Random variable not changing in "for" loop in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500217/random-variable-not-changing-in-for-loop-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:obno
set /a r1=%RANDOM% %% 10 + 1

:ob
for /L %%R in (1,1,%r1%) do CALL set /a n%%R=%%random%% %%%% 240 + 1
echo %r1%
echo %n1% %n2% %n3% %n4% %n5% %n6% %n7% %n8% %n9% %n10%
GOTO :EOF
```

Since %random% produces a random number 0..32767, your original code will waste a lot of time waiting for a number between 0 and 10. Also, it may generate 0.

The `%` operator is used for 'modulus'. Within a batch, you need to double it, so `%random% %% 10` produces 0..9

By `CALL`ing a command, you can avoid the need to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` BUT you also need to redouble any `%` you use, hence the doubling around `random` and quadrupling for the mod operator.

The `setlocal` isn't *strictly* necessary, BUT what it does is back out enviroment changes when the batch ends, so r1,n1..n10 simply no longer exist in the environment once the batch finishes. If you **OMIT** the `setlocal` then any variable set in one run will **REMAIN** set for a subsequent run, so if your first run sets n5 (and also therefore n1..n4) then if the second run sets r1=2, n3..n5 would be displayed with the stale data from the previous run.

Finally, if you allow r1=0 then since none of n1..n10 are set, the `echo %n1%...` command will be resolved to `echo`, will will show the `echo` status (Echo is on/off). This can be overcome by using the syntax `echo(%n1%...`. The character directly following the `O` has been found to do some strange things.
echo<kbd>Dot</kbd> for instance is traditional for a blak newline. The `(` may look odd and appear to 'unbalance' the nesting, but works quite happily to produce a newline with empty arguments.