# Can you make the code run a certain number of times?

Tags: batch-file

I know how to make the matrix code on Batch... is there a way to make it repeat the sequence of code a certain number of time?

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
Color 02
:start
Echo %random% %random% %random%
Goto start
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
Color 02

set count=0
:start
if %count%==20 goto:next
Echo %random% %random% %random%
set /a count+=1
Goto start

:next
pause
exit/b
```

Answer (score 3):

`FOR /L` can be used for loops, e. g. like this:

```
@echo off
Color 02
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,10) DO (
Echo %random% %random% %random%
)
```

`1,1,10` = *start,stepsize,end*

However, this will produce three different numbers, but the same tuple ten times.
To solve that, use the method from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500217/random-variable-not-changing-in-for-loop-in-windows-batch-file) question.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
Color 02
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,10) DO (
Echo !random! !random! !random!
)
```

variables with `!...!` are not cached before the loop, `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is required to enable that.