# How to Bypass Character Limit When Using CMD /c?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, character-limit

I'm writing a command line batch script in Windows 7 to upload multiple images for hosting, paste the url (using [this program](http://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/paste.html)) and filename into a line of text, then append the text to a file.

The following code gives me an error because the command "cmd /c" is too long.

```
@echo on
set DIR1="C:\Users\My\Desktop\temp"
set DIR2="C:\Misc\Programs\EasyImgur"
set DIR3="C:\Users\My\Desktop"

set DIR2=%DIR2:"=%
set DIR3=%DIR3:"=%

forfiles /m *.png /p %DIR1% /c "cmd /c %DIR2%\EasyImgur.exe /anonymous @path && timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL && paste > %DIR3%\temp.txt && set /p URL= < %DIR3%\temp.txt && echo if(G9="@fname",IMAGE(%URL%,3), >> %DIR3%\test.txt"

del %DIR3%\temp.txt

pause
exit
```

Is there any way around this? Some way to call all that text after "cmd /c" without breaking the character limit? I need all that done for every file in the directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use PowerShell or msys? (I'm not really kidding on either account.)

Comment: If you use `for` instead of `forfiles` you can convert the command into a subroutine.  (See `call /?`)

Comment: Well, `for` worked better as it did not have the character limit. My only problem now is why the following line doesn't import from the .txt: 
`paste > temp.txt && set /p URL=< temp.txt && echo %URL%`
It did write to the .txt file just fine, but why can't it import it to the URL variable?

Comment: The environment variable is expanded before the loop executes.  See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/6500797/886887 ; you can fix the problem either using delayed expansion (as per the linked answer) or by using a subroutine.

Comment: So close! I used delayed expansion, and I get exact text I want but its surrounded by quotes. How do I remove JUST the surrounding quotes, not the quotes in the inside? The text below is set to a variable called TEXT. My result is the following: `"if(G11="Akadi",IMAGE(http://i.imgur.com/mr7GBBD.png,3),"`

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the latest version of the code.  But looking at the original code, you're setting variables to values with quote marks around them and then removing the quote marks ... you realize you don't have to do that?  You can just say, for example, `set DIR1=C:\Misc\Programs\EasyImgur` ?

Comment: I posted the latest code as an answer. The directories are fine, and I want them in quotes in case there are spaces. The problem is the output.

Comment: The `set` command would still work even if there are spaces in the path.  But it *is* preferable to use quote marks to prevent any inadvertent spaces at the end of the line from becoming part of the value - you just need to put the opening quote before the variable name, as you've done in your posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Harry Johnston's help, I got it! Check it out.

The code is:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "DIR1=C:\Users\RyzaJr\Desktop\temp"
set "DIR2=C:\Misc\Programs\EasyImgur"

for %%a in (%DIR1%\*.png) do (

    "%DIR2%\EasyImgur.exe" /anonymous "%%a"
    timeout /t 4 /nobreak > NUL
    paste > temp.txt
    set /p URL= < temp.txt
    echo if(G11="%%~na",IMAGE(!URL!,3^), >> "output.txt"

)

del temp.txt
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you - the term you echo into the file has mismatched parenthesis though.

```
@echo on
set "DIR1=C:\Users\My\Desktop\temp"
set "DIR2=C:\Misc\Programs\EasyImgur"
set "DIR3=C:\Users\My\Desktop"

for %%a in ("%DIR1%\*.png") do (
  start "" /w /b "%DIR2%\EasyImgur.exe" /anonymous "%%a"
  set "flag="
   for /f "delims=" %%b in ('paste') do (
     if not defined flag >>"%DIR3%\test.txt" echo if(G9="%%~na",IMAGE(%%b,3^),
     set flag=1
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: Your answer is really close to working, but it needs the timeout because it doesn't upload to imgur fast enough, so the URLs were wrong. Yeah, I know about the mismatched parenthesis. I did it on purpose because the if() parameters would be nested inside eachother.

Comment: The start command with the /wait switch is supposed to stop the batch file proceeding until the command is finished.  Maybe the easyimgur.exe doesn't behave as a normal command line tool should behave - or the paste tool (presumably a clipboard reading utility) is at fault.  But does it work correctly if you put the timeout command back in?